# Can it be an issue to search engines if a primary image in a webpage is not declared with an image tag?

Tags: html, javascript, images, text, webpage

I was looking at my reports on google adsense, and on my mobile site, google reports that people see ads about 1% of the time. The stats are much more in my favor on the desktop site where the ads are above the images.

I have my site with the large picture formatted in the following manner:

```
<body>
text
<img src="imagetodisplay.jpg" width="xxx" height="xxx">
<script>
//page styling begins here.
</script>
</body>
```

When testing my site with webpagetest.org, it always shows that the large image begins loading before the adsense ads begin loading.

Here's a webpagetest.org report of my site: http://www.webpagetest.org/result/160404_TB_19N8/1/details/

What I want to do is attempt to change the order so that the first thing that loads is the web page text, then the ads, then the image so that everyone can see the ads fully loaded.

I feel I can accomplish this through javascript and by using the DIV tag to hold the image. (I'm hoping all cell phones support basic javascript).

My question is, would it be an acceptable practice SEO wise to create a DIV and user javascript to embed an image tag containing the actual primary image inside the DIV and have no image tags present (other than the one later created via javascript)? or will a search engine think of that idea in a negative way?

Also, I prefer not having the images themselves indexed in search engines, just only the original web pages that the images are loaded into.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you want to change order but let me clear that Google ads using asynchronous code to load ads without waiting itself i.e. **other things can be load without waiting of ads execution.**

You have implemented adsense ads at starting, so browser try to load that one first, and if ads server response well, then as usually browser ([Parallel mechanism apply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985431/max-parallel-http-connections-in-a-browser)) will load adsense ads simultaneously.

I don't suggest to [load adsense ads after text content](http://semplicewebsites.com/google-ads), **because Google always looks on content first before they serve ads**, so in such analytics I don't think you should focus on reports said by Webpagetest, or Google Insights.

In your case browser will try to execute adsense javascript at begin, and if it execute (as you have seen on test result), then ads will not going to display immediately, they will check your content first with adsense crawler then they will going to serve ads.

And, by using div and javascript tag, it will not going to affect in SEO. Just make sure, you're not violating Adsense terms.

By the way, if you have problem with Desktop and mobile ads, then [Adsense Media Query](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/6307124?hl=en&ref_topic=1307438) might be helpful for you. For images you can try lazyload trick, here is first one by [using server configuration](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/filter-lazyload-images#configuration), and second one is from [chris](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/lazy-loading-images/).

Comment: I'm more interested in loading adsense before any image content. I don't mind if adsense ads begin loading after all text content is loaded.

Comment: Then use lazy load things and put script at the end of body tag :)